# Expect Script - If SSH fails, use telnet

Tags: expect

I am iterating over a list of IP addresses and loging into them with SSH. But, some of them do not have SSH, but rather, only telnet. How do I tell Expect that: if SSH fails, try again but using telnet?

I know that a message "connection refused" is outputted when SSH fails, but when I try to use that as a condition, expect doesn't work with it...after the SSH attempt is refused, the script breaks.

Here is a code snippet - this is not working:

```
foreach line $MACHINES {
  spawn ssh -q $USER@$line
  expect {         
    -ex "ssh: connect to host $line port 22: Connection refused" {
      spawn telnet -l $USER@$line; continue
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance,
D

Comment: Run your script with `expect -d` and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have timeout handle the failed connection after your expect. Some systems may not even be kind enough to spit out connection refused. The following was tested on a system that does not inform the user it's spawn ssh timed out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

# invoke example ./telnet.exp 127.0.0.1 username password
set IP [lindex $argv 0]
set User [lindex $argv 1]
set Password [lindex $argv 2]

# Set timeout from default 10 seconds
set timeout 5
# connect  without asking yes/no for known_hosts
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $User@$IP
# I'm not being cheeky, I left out the p/P because I avoid regex where possible
expect {
    -nocase "refused" { spawn telnet $IP }
    timeout { spawn telnet $IP }
    "assword:" { send "$Password\r" }
}
interact
```

Here is my suggested change to your snippet (this is untested)

```
foreach line $MACHINES {
  spawn ssh -q $USER@$line
  expect {         
    -ex "ssh: connect to host $line port 22: Connection refused" {
      spawn telnet -l $USER@$line; continue
    }
    timeout {
      spawn telnet -l $USER@$line; continue
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pardon me for my belated response; I appreciate everyone's contribution.

I ended up using this little block successfully. I believe the "wait" command functions to remove the SSH process from the process list.

expect {

eof      {wait;spawn telnet -l $USER $line}

}

Answer (score 0):

Had to clean up some users on cisco routers (mixed bag ssh/telnet). Found this thread. Thanks for pointing me in a direction.

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
    set arg2 [lindex $argv 1]
    set timeout 120
    set username "router_username"
    set password "router_password"

    spawn telnet $arg1

            expect {
                    -re "Connection refused" { spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $arg1 -l $username }
                    "Username"       { send "$username\n"; }
                    }
            expect "Password"       { send "$password\n"; }
            expect "#$"             { send "conf t\n" ; }
            expect "config)#$"      { send "no username $arg2\n"; }

            expect {
                    -re "This operation will remove all username*" { send "\n"; exp_continue }
                    "config)#$"      { send "exit\n"; }
                    }

            expect "#$"             { send "wr\n" ; }
            expect "#$"             { send "end\n" ; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't do that. If an attacker is able to bring down the ssh service on that box, or man in the middle that box, he could force unencrypted telnet and get credentials to log into that server.

Don't try to use telnet as fallback for ssh. A script which is doing so can be easily exploited from remote.

Comment: This isn't an *answer* to the question. It's a comment.

Comment: In my eyes this does not apply to security related topics since not everybody reads the comments. In fact, I should have written this additionally in bold letters.